# Creating a Nested Serializer with two "Sibling" Models

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm attempting to get a JSON output similar to this:

```
{
    name: John Doe,
    best_buy_price: 420,
    best_sell_price: 69,
    player_profile: {
        tsn_link: https://a_link.com
    }
    playerlistingadvanced: { # This is where I'm having the issue
        sales_minute: 7,
    }
}
```

I have three models. `playerProfile` being the "main" model and `playerListing` and `playerListingAdvanced` are connected to `playerProfile` via a one-to-one relationship. `playerPfofile` will have its own endpoint, but I'd also like to create an endpoint that is primarily the listings and advanced listing data (as seen above).

Here is a stripped down version of the model.py file:

```
class PlayerProfile(models.Model):
    card_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=420, null=True)
    tsn_link = models.CharField(max_length=420, null=True)
   
 
class PlayerListing(models.Model):
    player_profile = models.OneToOneField(
        PlayerProfile,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=420, null=True)
    best_sell_price = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    best_buy_price = models.IntegerField(null=True)


class PlayerListingAdvanced(models.Model):
    player_profile = models.OneToOneField(
        PlayerProfile,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True)
    sales_minute = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2, null=True)
```

Here is the serializer.py I have tried, but haven't gotten to work.

```
class PlayerListingAdvancedForNestingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerListingAdvanced
        fields = (
            'sales_minute',
            'last_week_average_buy',
            'last_week_average_sell',
        )

class PlayerListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    player_profile = PlayerProfileForListingSerializer() # works
    playerlistingadvanced = PlayerListingAdvancedForNestingSerializer() #doesn't work
    
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerListing
        fields = (
            'name',
            'best_sell_price',
            'best_buy_price',
            'playerlistingadvanced',
            'player_profile'
        )
```

I'm assuming because playerListing and playerListingAdvanced are not directly related, that I'll need to do something else to make this work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). Your assuming is correct. Try this:

```
class PlayerListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    player_profile = PlayerProfileForListingSerializer()
    playerlistingadvanced = serializers.SerializerMethodField() 

    class Meta:
        model = PlayerListing
        fields = (
            'name',
            'best_sell_price',
            'best_buy_price',
            'playerlistingadvanced',
            'player_profile'
        )

    def get_playerlistingadvanced(self, obj: PlayerListing):
        player_profile = obj.player_profile
        if hasattr(player_profile, 'playerlistingadvanced'):
            serializer = PlayerListingAdvancedForNestingSerializer(instance=player_profile.playerlistingadvanced)
            return serializer.data
        return None
```